# preg_replace {* ... } with Class Delimiter Var's

Tags: php, preg-replace

I had written a little template class in PHP.

The template class use delimiters to replace vars

As example an easy template

`<title>{$WEBSITE_TITLE}</title>`

If I didn't assigned a placeholder they will stay in the site source code.
But as example I have a tag for notes and the user shouldn't see them if I didn't assigned them.

How can I replace that text with nothing if I didn't know the content inside of {$ ... } ?

`{$/SOME TEXT THAT WE DONT KNOW/}`

I tried a lot at the moment. My code for this action is:

```
preg_replace(
    "/\/$this->_leftDelimiter(.*?)$this->_rightDelimiter/",
    "",
    $this->_template
);
```

Class delimiter vars:

```
private $_leftDelimiter = '{$';
private $_rightDelimiter = '}';
```

Comment: Are you allowed to have a `}` in the tag? e.g. `{$foo}bar}`? --- As ana side, I'd look at wrapping your `leftDelimiter`/`rightDelimiter` in [`preg_quote`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put the class variables (the delimiters) outside the string :

```
preg_replace(
    "/".$this->_leftDelimiter."([^".$this->_rightDelimiter."]*?)".$this->_rightDelimiter."/",
    "",
    $this->_template
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function which allows you to replace the matched string depending of its content.

```
function teplateVars($matches) {
    // your logic here
    return $this->getStringForVariable($matches[1]);
}
preg_replace(
    "/".$this->_leftDelimiter."([^".$this->_rightDelimiter."]*?)".$this->_rightDelimiter."/",
    "templateVars",
    $this->_template
);
```

Also make sure that your _leftDelimiter and _rightDelimiter properties are correctly escaped so they can be used in a regular expression. The opening bracket and dollar symbol has special meaning

```
private $_leftDelimiter = '\{\$';
private $_rightDelimiter = '}';
```